# One class instance used automatically throughout process

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, logging

The python logging module once imported and instantiated will be so across the process, inside all modules and threads. How did they achieve that effect?

**Example:**

**myapp.py**

```
import logging
import mylib

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Started')
    mylib.do_something()
    logging.info('Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**mylib.py**

```
import logging

def do_something():
    logging.info('Doing something')
```

**myapp.log**

```
INFO:root:Started
INFO:root:Doing something
INFO:root:Finished
```

Comment: Why not take a look how `logging.py` was implemented? https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py

Comment: That's the standard behavior of imported modules. Do your own modules behave differently?

Comment: @Alik if the file didn't have 1742 lines I would say that your suggestion is good ;)

Comment: @alfasin you do not need to read whole file to understand how one instance is used everywhere in the module.

Comment: @Alik right, which is why your comment should include a more specific reference to the relevant lines ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a module is imported for the first time, the loaded module object is put into `sys.modules`.  Later imports will then find the module object and not reload the module.

The logging module has a bunch of module attributes which hold the state of logging configuration after the first import.